# What are the limitations and benefits of anti-aliasing and subpixel rendering respectively?

Tags: antialiasing, subpixel-rendering

Just like the question, I am wondering are there any limitations and benefits for these two techniques?

Comment: What *kind* of "anti-aliasing"? And what exactly do you mean by "subpixel rendering"?

Comment: Subpixel rendering is anti-aliasing just with different physics assumptions.